# Material-UI dialog font overwriting

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've made a custom User Confirmation Dialog from Material UI Dialog component like [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/creating-a-custom-userconfirmation-modal-with-the-react-router-prompt-dc1faa5a65a0)

I faced a problem to overwrite the Dialog's font. I can overwrite color or background color, but fonts in Dialog's header or buttons are inherited from Material-UI. I successfully overwrote Material-UI fonts in other components, but not in this part with callback:

```
const UserConfirmation = (
  message: string,
  callback: (shouldNavigate: boolean) => void
) => {
  const container = document.createElement('div')
  container.setAttribute('custom-confirmation-navigation', '')
  document.body.appendChild(container)
  const closeModal = (shouldNavigate: boolean) => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container)

    callback(shouldNavigate)
  }
  ReactDOM.render(
    <>
      <Dialog
        fullWidth={true}
        maxWidth="sm"
        open={true}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"

      >
        <DialogTitleWrapper
          style={{fontFamily: `BuenosAires !important`, color: `orange`}}
          >
          Discard draft?
        </DialogTitleWrapper>
        <DialogContent>
          <p> {message} </p>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActionsWrapper>
          <Button
            onClick={() => closeModal(true)}
            fullWidth={true}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Discard"
          />
          <div style={{ width: '80%' }} />
          <Button
            onClick={() => closeModal(false)}
            fullWidth={true}
            variant="contained"
            label="Cancel"
          />
        </DialogActionsWrapper>
      </Dialog>
    </>,
    container
  )
}
export default UserConfirmation
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank [Alex](https://stackexchange.com/users/6095640/alex)

That works brilliant for me:

`<DialogTitle  disableTypography="true">`

Also, buttons' labels were fixed by that: 
`label={<h5 style={{ textTransform: 'none' }}>Cancel</h5>}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `classes` object to Override or extend the styles applied to the component.
[here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes)

create custom styles like below

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({

  customDialogTitle: {
    fontFamily:'Impact'//sans-serif
  }
    });
```

and assign to `classes`

```
   <DialogTitle  disableTypography="true"

       classes={{
                 root: classes.customDialogTitle
                }}
    >
    .....
    </DialogTitle>
```

[sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/overriding-styles-with-classes-material-ui-l2b2k)

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers do not work anymore (MUI v5).
I found this question at the top of google search, so I update in case someone find useful.

You can override the fontFamily with `typography.fontFamily`.

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Georgia',
  }
})
```

If you use `next/font`, you can pass the `font.style.fontFamily` (Thanks to [the comment in the discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/45433#discussioncomment-5122376))
I previously used `inherit` and it functioned properly within the main body of the screen, but not in the presentation role (like in Dialog or Menu).

```js
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

let theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: inter.style.fontFamily,
  }
})
```